# Max application memory Limit in iPad?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have created iPad application which downloads images using web service. But my application crashes somewhere during manipulating with high quality images. So my question is - what is max memory limit for application running on iPad? When does the application hit LowMemoryWarning on iPad?

Comment: and this is a duplicate of about 10 questions.

Comment: @Jesse, of which you have helpfully identified exactly zero.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no per-application limit so to say. The amount of memory available to an application depends on the amount of free memory, which again depends on the amount of memory used by applications running in the background. These apps include permanently running system apps like SpringBoard, sometimes running system apps like Safari, iPod, etc and (when iOS 4 will come for iPad) user-apps that still run in background.

Nevertheless, I'd say an app should never use more than 50% of all available ram. On iPad this currently means 128 MB and should be quite a lot. Did you do a leak check on your app?

Comment: Ya I have done leak check on my app. It doesnt over 2 to 4 kb. Now i have limited my app memory upto 130 MB, if it crosses it i have reduced image quality and downloaded low quality Image.
Thank you.

Comment: Hi Max,

Are you sure that application can be around 100M. because i am developing an application for ipad to read pdf's.

For larger pdf's my app memory size is increasing to 25 to 30MB and it is giving me memory warnings. after giving 2 to 3 warning applcation is crashing.

Can you please let me know how to use upto 100MB for my application?

Comment: 30 MB seems to few to me, but there might be various reasons for that. Did you analyze the memory consumption of the whole system using Instruments?

Comment: For iPhone, its maximum of 10% of available memory for an application, you can see it on Device Console, as a reason to app quit.