# iOS device computational/memory limit

Tags: ios, ipad, device

I'm working on a game for iOS, and to start a new game the following steps are followed:

1. The user choose the number of pieces
2. Each piece is created through a loop
3. The game starts

On the simulator I can choose as many pieces as I want, and start as many games as I want, and the app is working fine.

But on a real device (my new iPad 3), the app crashes if I choose more than 400 pieces, and also if I start (say) 3 games with 150 pieces each. I've checked with breakpoints, it crashes in different lines: sometimes creating a piece, sometimes even after the game started. Unfortunately the console is not telling me anything.

I checked the app with instruments: there are not leaks at all, and the total allocation size is at most 4 MB. And I'm logging in didReceiveMemoryWarning in my AppDelegate, but it looks like it is never called.

My question is: **how should I behave to debug this? How can I understand what the computational/memory limits of a iOS device are?**

Comment: There is a post here which has code that determines available RAM: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5012886/knowing-available-ram-on-an-ios-device

Comment: Chances are, this is a different type of problem, possibly multiple problems. You should probably try to isolate it to try to determine what it is.

Answer (score 0):

If using too much memory is causing you this problem then try a `NSLog` in `didReciveMemoryWarning`. As for the memory limit I already saw a few posts here.
[How much memory does iOS allow apps to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169935/how-much-memory-does-ios-allow-apps-to-use)
or
[Max application memory Limit in iPad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585094/max-application-memory-limit-in-ipad) or
[iOS memory allocation - how much memory can be used in an application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044147/memory-limit-and-ios-memory-allocation-in-iphone-sdk)
And I think I can find a few more :)

Comment: I'm logging in didReceiveMemoryWarning in my AppDelegate, but it looks like it is never called